# WordPress CLI isn't working while use WordPress development repository

Tags: wp-cli

I cloned the repo from https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop.git

After that followed the README file from the downloaded code and installed node dependencies and execute the below commands in sequence for setup

```
npm install - Working fine
npm run build:dev - Working fine
npm run env:start - Working fine
npm run env:install - Giving error that WP CLI can't create a wp-config.php file. I am stuck at this point
```

System detail:
I am using Docker, NPM NODE, Windows 10 64bit OS

To fix it, I checked out various blog posts and googled them - They all are saying about permission, however, no one clearly says that you have to follow my clear steps.

**Screenshot of the error**

[image]

Comment: Is this a bug report?

Comment: I am not sure about that.

Comment: If you just to use wp-cli on your local environment, just download the wp-cli.phar as explained here https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/guides/installing/